# iMac iPhone USB Internet Sharing

Tags: iphone, imac, usb, internet

I have a MacBook Pro and a iMac. On the MacBook I see a network interface named "iPhone USB" in my Network Settings. On the MacBook the internet sharing over usb works fine. But on the iMac it doesn't work. On the iMac there is no "iPhone USB" interface and it doesn't appear a "New network device detected" window if I connect the iPhone to the iMac via USB. How can I add the "iPhone USB" network interface?

Please help.

Software Versions:
iMac 10.7.3
MacBook Pro 10.7.2
iPhone 5.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Turn off tethering on your iPhone
- Plug iPhone into iMac
- Turn tethering back on

Comment: No, does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out the [iPhone: Trouble Shooting Personal Hotspot](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2756) article. Specficially the USB Trouble Shooting information.

> If you are using USB to connect your computer to Personal Hotspot and you are unable to get an Internet connection, check your computer's network settings. You may need to adjust your computer's network settings to disconnect and reconnect the USB Ethernet interface.

> Open System Preferences > Network. Locate and select the Ethernet adapter listed, and then click the gear icon and choose Make Service Inactive. Then choose Make Service Active:
>
> [image: Eth Service]
>
> [image: Make Service Inactive]

Comment: I already tried this before I created this question. Apple provides no information about when the "New network device detected" window doesn't appear.

Comment: Do you have iTunes Running when you do this?

Comment: @MrDaniel :: Does iTunes running make any difference ?

Answer (score 0):

A couple other things to try are:

- Run the latest combo update
- Update iTunes to the latest version

The combo update has solved several of my networking problems over the years.